# «И поскольку» — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Нужна когда-нибудь между двумя этими словами запятая?

Comment: Когда-нибудь нужна, всякое бывает. Пожалуйста, задавайте  вопросы относительно конкретных предложений.

Comment: Мне кажется, что никогда не нужна.

Comment: Из Нацкорпуса: Алексей Варламов. Купавна // «Новый Мир», 2000 
Он был таким маленьким, что, когда они заходили с папой в карьер, едва доставал отцу до купальных трусов, и, поскольку песчаное, выложенное волнами, словно сливочное масло на витрине магазина, дно обрывалось у самого берега, мама боялась, что мальчик оступится, поскользнется, захлебнется и утонет.

Comment: 10. А. А. Мельников. Ветхое и новое в поэтическом цикле «Об опресноках» прп. Ефрема Сирина // «Актуальные вопросы современной науки», 2018 
И, поскольку слава и влияние их были очень велики как среди сирийцев, так и грекоязычных, уже вскоре после кончины прп. Ефрема среди тех и других появились многочисленные подражатели и «продолжатели» его творчества.

Answer (score 3):

**И** — это соединительный союз.
[**Поско́льку**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83) — союз подчинительный, присоединяет придаточное предложение причины.  Так как, потому что. *Поскольку ты согласен, я не возражаю. Не знаю, который час, поскольку часы стоят. Результат голосования не действителен, поскольку нет кворума*. **<Поскольку.., то, *в зн. союза*.** = Поскольку. *Поскольку все собрались, то начнём работу.*

> **4.** При «встрече» соединительного союза *и* и подчинительного союза возможны следующие случаи:
> **1)** запятая ставится только перед союзом *и* (независимо от того, соединяет ли он однородные члены предложения, самостоятельные предложения или соподчиненные придаточные части), если после придаточной части следует вторая часть двойного союза *(то, как* или *но*); в этом случае союз *и* присоединяет целое сложноподчиненное предложение...

*У Коли в Литве заболел брат, и он помчался туда, сидел в больнице, звонил ему, конечно, но он понимал, что роуминг дороговат для друга, **и поскольку** тот был щепетилен до безобразия, **то** он свел звонки к минимуму и старался выживать в одиночку* (Григорий Пашковский. А потом пошел снег).

> **2)** запятая ставится только после союза *и*, если он соединяет два однородных члена предложения или две соподчиненные придаточные части, причём дальше не следует вторая часть двойного союза...

*― Ну, что? ― поторопил Роман **и, поскольку** Петрик продолжал молчать, уточнил вопрос: ― Видели ― что?* (Давид Маркиш. Луковый мед).
[Поторопил Роман и, (придаточное), уточнил.]

> **3)** запятая ставится и перед союзом *и*, и после него, если союз соединяет два простых предложения (причем после придаточной части не следует вторая часть двойного союза)...

*В 2005 году все рекорды по годовому количеству ураганов были побиты, **и, поскольку** имен заранее не запасли, пришлось после того, как двадцать первый ураган в Атлантике уже прошел, последующие ураганы обозначать просто греческими буквами: альфа, бета, гамма, дельта* (А. М. Городницкий. Тайны и мифы науки. В поисках истины).
[Рекорды были побиты, и, (придаточное), пришлось ураганы обозначать.]

Под эту часть правила подпадает и пунктуация в предложении Алексея Варламова.

[§ 36. Запятая на стыке двух союзов](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140)