# О доме: «пытался покоситься на разные стороны»

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, глаголы

Недавно отвечала на вопрос ([«И поскольку» — пунктуация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473182/%D0%98-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)), в [Нацкорпусе](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CrgBEoYBCoMBChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluEmwKFwoDbGV4EhAKDtGC0YPRh9C10YDQtdC3CgoKBGZvcm0SAgoACgsKBWdyYW1tEgIKAAoJCgNzZW0SAgoAChUKB3NlbS1tb2QSCgoIc2VtfHNlbXgKCQoDc3luEgIKAAoLCgVmbGFncxICCgAqJgoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKNylqKquzrUGQAVaA2xleGoEMC45NXgAMgIIAToBATAB) попалось вот такое предложение:

*Тучерез стоял на двух толстых курьих ногах, содержал тринадцать разновеликих этажей и, поскольку не единожды уже **пытался покоситься на разные стороны**, подпирался тремя костылями из рельсов* (Г. С. Зеленина. Куриная Слепота и ее обитательницы // «Волга», 2014).

Не знаю, как грамотно сформулировать вопрос.
Мне кажется, что нужна или другая комбинация глаголов, или другой предлог.
Или все правильно, "комфортно"?

[Тучерез](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/384864/%D1%82%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7) (= небоскрёб)

Comment: Все ок. Дом покосился на юг. Дом покосился на сторону. Дом пытался покоситься то на одну, то на другую сторону. Дом пытался покоситься на разные стороны.

Comment: Римма, мне тоже "комфортно", и юмор присутствует.

Comment: Да, хотела бы я посмотреть на этот *курьеногий многокостыльный* домик!.. Но — все равно какое-то смущение присутствует. Может, это связано со значением "покоситься" — слегка наклониться. Обычно мы говорим не "на сторону", а "в сторону". Или вправо-влево. Не?..